# Display an array with objects and icons

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects

```
 arr = [
{'name': value},
{'name': value},
{'name': value},
...............
]
```

Value is `svg icon`. I want to display this in the template with *ngFor

```
<div> arr.name </div>
<svg> arr.value </svg>
```

Are there ways to do this?

Comment: Is your array correct like this :  arr = [
{'name': value},
] or you mean like this : arr = [ { 'name': 'exp1' , 'value' : 'exp1' } , { 'name': 'exp2' , 'value' : 'exp2' }]

Comment: is your sample array is like `arr = [
{'name': 'value1'},
{'name': 'value2'},
{'name': 'value3'},
...............
] `

Comment: this is confusing, is the key always "name" or is that placeholder for a variable value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming 'name' is just a placeholder and the key is actually a variable value, you could do something like:

in controller, map it into something usable:

```
 arr = [
{'name': value},
{'name': value},
{'name': value},
...............
]
mapped = this.arr.map(i => {
  let name = Object.keys(i)[0];
  let value = i[name];
  return {name, value};
});
```

then in template do exactly what you have:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of mapped">
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  <svg>{{item.value}}</svg>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
arr = [{
    'name': 'exp1',
    'value': 'exp1'
}, {
    'name': 'exp2',
    'value': 'exp2'
}]
```

and in HTML :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of arr">
   <div> {{ item.name }}</div>
   <svg> {{ item.value }} </svg>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Why offer options for changing the array, if obviously there is no such task?

Answer (score 0):

Create function to getKey() and getValue() in object in .ts

```
getKey(object)
{
  let keys= Object.keys(object);
  return keys[0];

}
getValue(object)
{
  let keys= Object.keys(object);
  return object[keys[0]];
}
```

In HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of arr | keyvalue">
  <div>{{getKey(item.value)}}</div>
  <svg>{{getValue(item.value)}}</svg>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: this would be a performance nightmare. It would run on every item in the array and rerender on every single change detection cycle.  Map the array once.